# Sharing variables over multiple js files

Tags: javascript, html

So, I have 2 html files with their corresponding JavaScript file. I can not make it so when I check a checkbox in the first html file to update the dashboard values from the second file.

I tried to use import/request function to use the variable which modified when the checkbox checked from the first js file into the second js file but it didn't work.

This is my code

**html 1**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <title>Energenius</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Static/living.css">
    <script type = "module" src="Static/living.js"></script>



    
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="dashboard">
    <header>
        <div class="f fe">
        <div class="icon icon-w"></div>
        <div class="heading">
            <nav>
                <label for="touch"><span class="account">parter</span class="account"></label>               
                <input type="checkbox" id="touch"> 

                <ul class="slide">
                    <li><a href="/E1L">Apartament 1</a></li> 
                    <li><a href="/E2L">Apartament 2</a></li>


                  </ul>
            </nav>
            <h2 class="title">Cloudy</h2>
        </div>
        </div>
        
        <div class="weather f">
        <div>
            <strong id="volt">Consumption Analytics</strong>
            <p style="color: white;"><button id="analytics" onclick="redirect();"></button></p>
        </div>
        <div>

        </div>
    </header>
    <section>
    <!-- Category -->
        <div class="category">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#!" class="active">Living Room</a></li>

        </ul>
        </div>
    <!-- Appliances -->
    <form>
        <div class="appliances">

        <div class="appliance">
            <input type="checkbox" name="a" id="a"  onchange="handleChange1(); location.reload();"  `>
            <label for="a">
            <i class="l"></i>
            <strong>Lamp</strong>
            <span data-o="opened" data-c="closed"></span>
            <small></small>
            </label>
        </div>
        

    </form>
    </section>
    </div>
</body>
```

**js of the first file**

```
function handleChange1() {
    var myCheckbox = document.getElementById("a");
    if (document.getElementById("a").checked) {
        history.pushState(null, null, "/P");
        myCheckbox.setAttribute("checked", "checked");
        localStorage.setItem("aChecked", "true");
    } else {
        history.pushState(null, null, "/p");
        myCheckbox.removeAttribute("checked");
        localStorage.setItem("aChecked", "false");
    }
}

window.onload = function() {
    var aChecked = localStorage.getItem("aChecked");
    if (aChecked === "true") {
        document.getElementById("a").setAttribute("checked", "checked");
    }
}

document.getElementById("a").addEventListener("change", function() {
    handleChange1();
    location.reload();
});

function redirect(){
    var button = document.getElementById("analytics");
    button.onclick = location.href="analytics";

    window.addEventListener( "pageshow", function ( event ) {
        var historyTraversal = event.persisted || ( typeof window.performance != "undefined" && window.performance === 2 );
        if ( historyTraversal ) {
          window.location.reload();
        }
      });
}
```

**Second html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" >
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Analytics</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="Static/analytics.css">
  
</head>
<body>
<!-- partial:index.partial.html -->
<section class="dashboard" id="main-column">
  
  <div id="sensorValues">
    <div class="sensor-values">
      <div class="volts" id="volts">0</div>
      <label>Volts</label>
    </div>
    <div class="sensor-values">
      <div class="amps" id="amps">0</div>
      <label>Amps</label>
    </div>
    <div class="sensor-values">
      <div class="moisture" id="moisture">0</div>
      <label>Cost Total</label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="sensorData"></div>
</section>
<!-- partial -->
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0-alpha1/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highcharts/4.2.1/highcharts.js'></script>
<script src='https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/4579/darkThemeHighCharts.js'></script>
<script  src="Static/analytics.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

**js of the second html**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var $delay = 1000,
            totalPoints = 25,
            $voltageDisplay = $('div.volts'),
            $currentDisplay = $('div.amps'),
            $moistureDisplay = $('div.moisture');
            
            function getRandomInt(min, max) {
                let reading = (Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);
                return (Math.round(reading * 2) / 2)
            }
        
            function updateVoltage(value) {
                $voltageDisplay.html(value.toFixed(1));
            }
            
            function updateCurrent(value) {
                $currentDisplay.html(value.toFixed(1));
            }
            
            function updateMoisture(value) {
                $moistureDisplay.html(value.toFixed(1) + '<span>RON</span>');
            }
            
            function updateSensorDisplayValues(d) {
                updateVoltage(d[0]);
                updateCurrent(d[1]);
                updateMoisture(d[2]);
            }
            
            Highcharts.setOptions({
                global: {
                    useUTC: false
                },
                plotOptions: {
                    series: {
                        marker: {
                            enabled: false
                        }
                    }
                },
                tooltip: {
                    enabled: false
                }
            });
            
            $('#sensorData').highcharts({
                chart: {
                    type: 'spline',
                    events: {
                        load: function() {
                            var voltage = this.series[0];
                            var current = this.series[1];
                            var moisture = this.series[2];
                            var x, volts, amps, mPercent;
                            
                            setInterval(function() {
                                x = (new Date()).getTime(),
                                volts =  1;
                                amps =  1;
                                mPercent =  1;
                                
                                voltage.addPoint([x, volts], false, true);
                                current.addPoint([x, amps], false, true);
                                moisture.addPoint([x, mPercent], true, true);
                            
                            updateSensorDisplayValues([volts, amps, mPercent]);
                        }, $delay);
                    }
                }
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Sensor Data'
            },
            xAxis: {
                type: 'datetime',
                tickPixelInterval: 500
            },
            yAxis: [{
                title: {
                    text: 'VOLTAGE',
                    style: {
                        color: '#2b908f',
                        font: '13px sans-serif'
                    }
                },
                min: 0,
                max: 15,
                plotLines: [{
                    value: 0,
                    width: 1,
                    color: '#808080'
                }]
            }, {
                title: {
                    text: 'CURRENT',
                    style: {
                        color: '#90ee7e',
                        font: '13px sans-serif'
                    }
                },
                min: 0,
                max: 4,
                opposite: true,
                plotLines: [{
                    value: 0,
                    width: 1,
                    color: '#808080'
                }]
            }, {
                title: {
                    text: 'COST ⠀TOTAL',
                    style: {
                        color: '#f45b5b',
                        font: '13px sans-serif'
                    }
                },
                min: 0,
                max: 100,
                opposite: true,
                plotLines: [{
                    value: 0,
                    width: 1,
                    color: '#808080'
                }]
            }],
            tooltip: {
                formatter: function() {
                    var unitOfMeasurement = this.series.name === 'VOLTAGE' ? ' V' : ' A';
                    return '<b>' + this.series.name + '</b><br/>' +
                    Highcharts.numberFormat(this.y, 1) + unitOfMeasurement;
                }
            },
            legend: {
                enabled: true
            },
            exporting: {
                enabled: false
            },
            series: [{
                name: 'VOLTAGE',
                yAxis: 0,
                style: {
                    color: '#2b908f'
                },
                data: (function() {
                    var data = [],
                    time = (new Date()).getTime(),
                    i;
                    
                    for (i = -totalPoints; i <= 0; i += 1) {
                        data.push({
                            x: time + i * $delay,
                            y: 1
                        });
                    }
                    return data;
                }())
            }, {
                name: 'CURRENT',
                yAxis: 1,
                data: (function() {
                    var data = [],
                    time = (new Date()).getTime(),
                    i;
                    
                    for (i = -totalPoints; i <= 0; i += 1) {
                        data.push({
                            x: time + i * $delay,
                            y: 2
                        });
                    }
                    return data;
                }())
            }, {
                name: 'Cost Total',
                yAxis: 2,
                data: (function() {
                    var data = [],
                    time = (new Date()).getTime(),
                    i;
                    
                    for (i = -totalPoints; i <= 0; i += 1) {
                        data.push({
                            x: time + i * $delay,
                            y: 3
                        });
                    }
                    return data;
                }())
            }]
        });
    });
```

Comment: Use `localStorage` or `sessionStorage` to save data between page loads.

Comment: Typically the solution is to send information about the user's input to the server, where it gets stored in some kind of database. Then, on the other page, issue a request to ask the server for that information, which it will retrieve from the database.

Answer (score 0):

HTML itself is stateless, and to overcome this limitation and share variables or data between different parts of a web application, developers leverage Web Storage APIs. These APIs provide a means to store and retrieve data on the client side, allowing web applications to maintain stateful behavior, remember user preferences, and create a more interactive and personalized user experience.

Example code to help you jumpstart and get the idea :

#### First Code

```js
function handleChange1() {
  var myCheckbox = document.getElementById("a");
  if (document.getElementById("a").checked) {
    history.pushState(null, null, "/P");
    myCheckbox.setAttribute("checked", "checked");
    localStorage.setItem("aChecked", "true");
  } else {
    history.pushState(null, null, "/p");
    myCheckbox.removeAttribute("checked");
    localStorage.setItem("aChecked", "false");
  }
}

window.onload = function() {
  var aChecked = localStorage.getItem("aChecked");
  if (aChecked === "true") {
    document.getElementById("a").setAttribute("checked", "checked");
  }
}

document.getElementById("a").addEventListener("change", function() {
  handleChange1();
  location.reload();
});

function redirect(){
  var button = document.getElementById("analytics");
  button.onclick = location.href="analytics";

  window.addEventListener( "pageshow", function ( event ) {
    var historyTraversal = event.persisted || ( typeof window.performance != "undefined" && window.performance === 2 );
    if ( historyTraversal ) {
      window.location.reload();
    }
  });
}
```

#### Second Code

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  // ... (existing code)

  function updateSensorDisplayValues(d) {
    updateVoltage(d[0]);
    updateCurrent(d[1]);
    updateMoisture(d[2]);
    localStorage.setItem("sensorData", JSON.stringify(d)); // Save sensor data
  }

  setInterval(function() {
    x = (new Date()).getTime(),
    volts = 1;
    amps = 1;
    mPercent = 1;

    voltage.addPoint([x, volts], false, true);
    current.addPoint([x, amps], false, true);
    moisture.addPoint([x, mPercent], true, true);

    updateSensorDisplayValues([volts, amps, mPercent]);
  }, $delay);
});
```